# Scikit: calculate precision and recall using cross_val_score function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision, logistic-regression

I'm using scikit to perform a logistic regression on spam/ham data. 
X_train is my training data and y_train the labels('spam' or 'ham') and I trained my LogisticRegression this way:

```
classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

If I want to get the accuracies for a 10 fold cross validation, I just write:

```
 accuracy = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=10)
```

I thought it was possible to calculate also the precisions and recalls by simply adding one parameter this way:

```
precision = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='precision')
recall = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='recall')
```

But it results in a `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label: array(['ham', 'spam'], dtype='|S4')
```

Is it related to the data (should I binarize the labels ?) or do they change the `cross_val_score` function ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To compute the recall and precision, the data has to be indeed binarized, this way:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
lb.fit(y_train)
```

To go further, i was surprised that I didn't have to binarize the data when I wanted to calculate the accuracy:

```
accuracy = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=10)
```

It's just because the accuracy formula doesn't really need information about which class is considered as positive or negative: (TP + TN) / (TP + TN + FN + FP). We can indeed see that TP and TN are exchangeable, it's not the case for recall, precision and f1.

Answer (score 10):

I encountered the same problem here, and I solved it with

```
# precision, recall and F1
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

lb = LabelBinarizer()
y_train = np.array([number[0] for number in lb.fit_transform(y_train)])

recall = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='recall')
print('Recall', np.mean(recall), recall)
precision = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='precision')
print('Precision', np.mean(precision), precision)
f1 = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='f1')
print('F1', np.mean(f1), f1)
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you showed above is correct. Looks like a problem with the data you're using. The labels don't need to be binarized, as long as they're not continuous numbers.

You can prove out the same syntax with a different dataset:

```
iris = sklearn.dataset.load_iris()
X_train = iris['data']
y_train = iris['target']

classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

print cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='precision')
print cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='recall')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use cross-validation like this to get the f1-score and recall :

```
print('10-fold cross validation:\n')
start_time = time()
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X,y, cv=10, scoring ='f1')
recall_score=cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X,y, cv=10, scoring ='recall')
print(label+" f1: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f) [%s]" % (scores.mean(), scores.std(), 'DecisionTreeClassifier'))
print("---Classifier %s use %s seconds ---" %('DecisionTreeClassifier', (time() - start_time)))
```

for more scoring-parameter just see [the page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

you should specify which of the two labels is positive (it could be ham) :

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, precision_score

precision = make_scorer(precision_score, pos_label="ham")

accuracy = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring = precision)
```